# dead_strip flag conflicts with another one

Tags: ios

I am trying to build a framework1 in which I have to include another one (framework2) by weak linking. For this framework2 to be included, I have to set in the target the `Dead Code Stripping` to YES, otherwise I get duplicate symbols error (at least this is what happened when I included framework2 directly into a project alongside with framework1. But now I have to combine these 2).

However when I am setting this flag to YES I get a different error, saying:

```
ld: -r and -dead_strip cannot be used together
```

Any idea what that `-r` flag could be, so I can disable it, or some other solution to this problem?

Thank you in advance

Comment: I think you should solve the fundamental issue first: "I get duplicate symbols error".  That isn't some trivial issue you should solve with work-arounds like weak linking.  Face it head on.

Comment: I wasn't trying to create a workaround, the weak linking was requested by the customer. Both frameworks were functional before and made by a 2nd and 3rd person. My task is only to combine them.

Answer (score 0):

`-r` is emiited when you set `MACH_O_TYPE = mh_object` "Relocatable Object File`. In that case dead code stripping is not supported, as it happens at a later stage.

Disable one or the other to resolve this. I recommend disabling dead code stripping as it should be done at your final static/dynamic library.